# Changing different tables from dropdown (onChange)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I am trying to hide and show multiply tables from dropdown onChange. But i have to many tables and it is taking to long to change the table this is the js code that changes the tables :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Table1 , #Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
$('#Table1 , #Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').hide();

$("#dropdown").on('change', function () {
    var tableId = $(":selected", this).val();
    if (tableId == 'table0') {
        $('#Table1 , #Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table1 , #Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').hide();
    } else if (tableId == 'Table1') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table6 , #Table7 , #Table8').hide();
        $('#Table1').DataTable();
        $('#Table1').show();
        Table1F();
    } else if (tableId == 'Table6') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table1 , #Table7 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table1 , #Table7 , #Table8').hide();
        $('#Table6').DataTable();
        $('#Table6').show();
        Table6F();
    } else if (tableId == 'Table7') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table5 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').hide();
        $('#Table7').DataTable();
        $('#Table7').show();
        Table7F();
    } else if (tableId == 'Table5') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table4 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').hide();
        $('#Table5').DataTable();
        $('#Table5').show();
        Table5F();
    } else if (tableId == 'Table4') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table8').hide();
        $('#Table4').DataTable();
        $('#Table4').show();
        Table4F();
    }
    else if (tableId == 'Table8') {
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table2 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').hide();
        $('#Table8').DataTable();
        $('#Table8').show();
        Table8F();
    }
    else if (tableId == 'Table2') {
        $('#Table8 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table8 , #Table3 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').hide();
        $('#Table2').DataTable();
        $('#Table2').show();
        Table2F();
    }
    else if (tableId == 'Table3') {
        $('#Table8 , #Table2 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#Table8 , #Table2 , #Table5 , #Table7 , #Table1 , #Table6 , #Table4').hide();
        $('#Table3').DataTable();
        $('#Table3').show();
        Table3F();
    }
});
```

Is there any way i can customize this part of code and make it faster and with less code.I'm using DataTables so i need to destroy it too this code is working but it is slow.

Edit :

```
function Table1F() {
var url = TABLE1_URL + '?AllRows=True&Fields=Data1&Fields=Data2&Fields=Data3&Fields=Data4&Fields=Data5&Fields=Data6&Fields=Data7&Fields=Data8';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        $("#Table1").DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            aLengthMenu: [
                [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
            ],
            iDisplayLength: 25,
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'excel', title: 'data' }
            ],
            data: data.List,
            processing: true,
            columns: [
                { data: 'Data1' },
                { data: 'Data2' },
                { data: 'Data3' },
                { data: 'Data4' },
                { data: 'Data5' },
                { data: 'Data6' },
                { data: 'Data7' },
                { data: 'Data8' },
            ],
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        swal("Error", errorThrown, "error");
    }
});
```

This is one of my functions and how i call the data from the server
All other functions are the same but with different data.

Comment: Why do you keep destroying and recreating the tables if all you want to do is to show/hide them?

Comment: How many hows each table has? Are you load all table rows on the front end, or you enable Server-side processing?

Comment: @LuttiCoelho Some tables have more than 1000 rows i call all rows on front end

Comment: That is one of your problems. Jquery datatables are not very fast when handle too much lines. I suggest you to change your tables to show at max 100 rows per table and do the hardwork (filter, paginate, order) in the backend. You'll feel a huge difference on performance.

Comment: @ChrisG I also need to destroy them because if i don't destroy , the paging numbers and the search box will not be hidden.

Comment: That's only an issue when you show/hide the table elements; use wrappers instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tv8eum2z/

Comment: @ChrisG This will also be a poor solution as you still have multiple tables. All the table data should be saved in a variable and based on selection, datatable has to be updated with new set of data

Comment: @Cerlin updating the tables is what's slow, the very thing OP is trying to fix. And who's to say these tables all have the same columns? Having all eight of them with seven hidden is a memory hog but fast.

Comment: Nope. Destroying and recreating is whats making this slow, not updating it. Creating 10 DataTables with all data will be even bigger load on the browser than what i have said.

Comment: He said change but not where in code he is updating(to quote u **changing**). He is destroying and recreating which is for sure more memory consuming and slower than updating the data as datatable just have to redraw and not initialise and then redraw. Also it would be great if you can show the code in which OP is updating(**changing**) the data.

Comment: I edited the question and added one functions so you can see how i get the data from server.

Comment: I suggest you to try @ChrisG solution jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/tv8eum2z because it is the fast way. Without destroy and reacreate your tables you will have less operations that will consume a lot of memory. **But** As I said before jquery datatables will be very slow when handle high volume of data. So after resolve the problem of destroy and recreate I suggest you to handle each table data with **server-side processing** https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can do something like this

```
$("#dropdown").on('change', function () {
    var tableId = $(":selected", this).val();
    var selectedTable = $('#'+ $(":selected", this).val());
    var allTables = $('table');

    allTables.DataTable().destroy()
    allTables.hide()

    selectedTable.DataTable()
    selectedTable.hide()

    eval(tableId+"F()")
}
```

**NOTE: I personally think you have fundamental problems in your design. You should not be using multiple tables like this as it would take a huge hit in performance. Use single table with different data on request.**

Comment: Who ever downvoted this, please provide reason before down voting

Comment: It was me. You're still calling `DataTable()` each time the selection changes, so this will not fix the slowness, at all. And using `eval()` is a no-no.

Comment: I have just posted a simplified version of what OP has asked. Not an over all solution as the design itself is flawed

Comment: OP says their code works but is slow. You rewrote the code to make it shorter, keeping the slowness. Precisely not the answer to OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Set all Tables to hidden using **css** and then change the css using **javascript** code

```
 document.getElementById("#table").style.display = "none"
```

and **put all table id in an array**